# Multiple frequencies

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency, information, electrical-engineering, signal-processing

could someone please inform me how it is possible to send multiple frequencies down one wire? I’m referring specifically to a communication protocol known as HART. It seems they send a 4-20mA signal as well as digital information of varying frequencies. However the digital information has no effect on the 4-20mA signal. How can this be? Surely any digital information will alter the current in the 4-20mA signal? I believe the technique is called FSK. Can someone please assist?

Comment: Every time you make a land-line phone call you are sending multiple frequencies down one wire. Now, arranging it so that a digital signal does not interfere with a classic current loop takes a bit of engineering, but a high enough frequency digital signal and a low pass filter for the current loop will do pretty well.

Comment: Re, "...the digital information has no effect on the 4-20mA signal..." That is not true at all. What is true is that, _[filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(signal_processing))_ can be used to separate the combined signal into distinct _[frequency bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_band)_.  Presumably, the value of the analog sensor can be reconstructed by looking only at the very lowest frequencies, while the digital information can be reconstructed by looking only at higher frequencies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I’m still struggling a bit with the concept. When I think of signals travelling through a wire, I just think of a stream of electrons. How can they differentiate between one stream and another if they are being processed at the same time? As for the frequencies, in this context is it right to think of it as the voltage varying so as to generate a wave like form?

Comment: Hi Solomon, yes that is right but what technique to filters use to differentiate between high and low frequencies? I just can’t understand how one set of electrons can be differentiated from another set. I know I’m missing something fairly fundamental but not sure what?

Comment: An AC signal in a wire is not a "stream" of electrons. Since the AC signal reverse polarity twice per cycle, it's more like the sea of electrons in the wire is sloshing back and forth. Now you can have signals of different frequency on the wire the same way you can send multiple audio waves of different frequencies through the air.

Comment: Thanks. I understand this for an AC signal but surely in a telephone wire, this is not what is happening? The “stream” is flowing in one direction along with multiple other “streams” that vary in frequency somehow. They are then processed by something that can determine the difference?

Comment: do not think of information as being carried by electrons sloshing back and forth, a better, or rather more effective way of thinking is to say that between the wires you have the electromagnetic field traveling at the speed of light is carrying the information. The purpose of the wire is to *direct* the EM wave from the generator to the load but the EM wave (ie., *light*) itself is the one that carries the information by having multiple frequencies, amplitudes, phases as controlled by the generator.

Comment: The electronic circuits that isolate different frequency bands from a mixed signal (a.k.a., "filters") can be more or less sophisticated depending on how well you need them to do the job. The simplest filter consists of nothing more than a capacitor and a resistor. At its most sophisticated, filter design becomes a math-intensive, book-level topic.  You can start learning about it on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_filter How far you want to go from there is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Frequencies are just colors, literally. Your eyes are not very good below 500THz frequencies but diode detectors can sense all the way down to a few Hz. If you look through a metal pipe you can see colors very well, so just imagine red for "0" and blue for "1" and you have visible FSK (frequency shift keying). A pair of wires can direct light at any frequency (visible and otherwise) just like, or almost like, a pipe can.

Comment: Thanks for this. It’s a really good analogy for me. I understand this from a wave with varying frequencies but I don’t really get it for electrons flowing through a wire. How can they be made to look like a wave and how can something detect the difference?

Comment: Sorry, I saw your response in the above thread. So, basically I’m thinking about how electrons move through a wire in the wrong way?

Comment: the problem is not that electrons do not slosh back and forth while the EM wave is moving along the wire but that it does not help in understanding what is happening. Energy between the generator and the load does move with the speed of the EM wave (the speed of light, yes!) between the wires while the electrons are moving at a speed of about mm/sec (millimeter per sec) in the wire. Remember that water molecules describe a kind of circular motion while the surface wave moves, interferes, diffracts, spreads out, the molecules do not move that way at all.

Comment: and more importantly, what I said was no analogy; when you will be studying transmission lines/Maxwell equations/EM waves you will learn and understand that energy is actually transported *between* the wires and not *in* them just as visible light in a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The 4mA-20mA protocol is a standard interface for instrumentation sensors, but it can only measure one parameter. Pressure, temperature, fluid level, etc.  The current is a DC analog signal.  4mA is one end of the sensor scale and 20mA the other.

HART is a FSK (Frequency Shift Keying) digital communications protocol modulated on top of the DC protocol.  1.2kHz represents 1 and 2.2kHz is 0.  The amplitude of this signal is 0.5mA Peak.

[image: HART frequencies]

If the analog signal is 8mA, the digital modulation creates a signal from 7.5mA to 8.5mA.  Essentially, one is DC and the other AC.

The 4-20mA receiver would not be sensitive enough to see the AC and the digital receiver can filter out the DC.  HART uses the existing 2-wire 4-20mA infrastructure to transfer digital and analog signals.

Comment: Ah right - thanks that was a really good explanation for me. So the total current in the wire does increase, it’s just the receivers can somehow differentiate between the two signals. I’m still struggling to visualise it on a conceptual level though as it is still just electrons in a wire. The DC would be just like a constant stream and the AC a varying one but it is still just electrons moving through a wire so can’t think how something would be able to distinguish?

Comment: At the receiving end, a resistor is used to convert the current to voltage and ac or DC voltages can be filtered out as required to leave the desired signal.  Electrons don't care if the potential difference is ac or DC.  The average would be a constant DC stream with an ac wave increasing or decreasing the flow as required.  Individual electrons would only flow centimeters, while it is the net flow of electrons which matters.  1A = $6.25 × 10^{18}$ electrons.